# How to migrate a React app with multiple Node processes from http to secure https with Ubuntu Apache2

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, https, apache2

I have a React app and two Node Express (REST API) processes running under http (Apache2) on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 20.04 Droplet.  The React app runs on port 80 while the Node Express apps run on port 4000 and 4001 respectively.

All instances of `http` have been replaced with `https` in my code.  However, ports 4000 and 4001 are not secure ports like 443 is.  I have Certbot installed with no errors.

What is the recommended way to 'migrate' from http to secure https in this case?  Will I need to set up a reverse proxy on the Apache2 web server?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You should setup a process manager (like [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)) to handle the node applications and then use HTTP proxy to expose those apps ports and bind them to domains and locations using `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`. Check this nice article [Set Up a Node.js App for a Website With Apache on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/web-development/nodejs-for-a-website-with-apache-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: @ChristosLytras I am using PM2, works great.  Nowhere does it show in the article you linked how to get both Node processes running under https.  Still searching for the answer.

Comment: The domain you will bind the PM2 process will have an SSL certificate using Appache SSL module (`sudo a2enmod ssl`). In your question you're trying to match application ports directly to be served. If you're using PM2, then you don't have to change `http` instances to `https`, because PM2 will bind them using `http` and then Apache SSL module will proxy the PM2 processes to the HTTP server. There are countless articles regarding how to setup SSL in apache. Create a domain that supports SSL using `<VirtualHost *:443>...</VirtualHost>` and then use `ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/`.